# Trouble understanding the non-obvious use of backslash inside of backticks

Tags: bash, backslash

I have read a ton of pages including the bash manual, but still find the "non-obvious" use of backslashes confusing.

If I do:

```
echo \*
```

it prints a single asterisks, this is normal as I am escaping the asterisks making it literal.

If I do:

```
echo \\*
```

it prints `\*`
This also seems normal, the first backslash escapes the second.

If I do

```
echo `echo \\*`
```

It prints the contents of the directory. But in my mind it should print the same as `echo \\*` because when that is substituted and passed to echo.  I understand this is the non-obvious use of backslashes everyone talks about, but I am struggling to understand WHY it happens.

Also the bash manual says

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.

But it doesn't define what the "literal meaning on backslash" is.  Is it as an escape character, a continuation character, or just literally a backslash character?

Also, it says it retain it's literal meaning, except when followed by ... So when it's followed by one of those three characters what does it do?  Does it only escape those three characters?

Comment: "Literal meaning" means that it's actually an ASCII code point 92 in the string, not part of a digraph.

Comment: Note that `echo \\*` and `echo $(echo \\*)` do print the same thing, and that `$()` is generally the preferred method for calling a command in a subshell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mostly for historical interest since `` `...` `` command substitution has been superseded by the cleaner `$(...)` form. No new script should ever use backticks.

Here's how you evaluate a `$(command)` substitution

1. Run the command

Here's how you evaluate a `` `string` `` command substitution:

1. Determine the span of the string, from the opening backtick to the closing unescaped backtick (behavior is undefined if this backtick is inside a string literal: the shell will typically either treat it as literal backtick or as a closing backtick depending on its parser implementation)
2. Unescape the string by removing backslashes that come before one of the three characters dollar, backtick or backslash. This following character is then inserted literally into the command. A backslash followed by any other character will be left alone.

   - E.g. `Hello\\ World` will become `Hello\ World`, because the `\\` is replaced with `\`
   - `Hello\ World` will also become `Hello\ World`, because the backslash is followed by a character other than one of those three, and therefore retains its literal meaning of just being a backslash
   - `\\\*` will become `\\*` since the `\\` will become just `\` (since backslash is one of the three), and the `\*` will remain `\*` (since asterisk is not)
3. Evaluate the result as a shell command (this includes following all regular shell escaping rules on the result of the now-unescaped command string)

So to evaluate `` echo `echo \\*` ``:

1. Determine the span of the string, here `echo \\*`
2. Unescape it according to the backtick quoting rules: `echo \*`
3. Evaluate it as a command, which runs echo to output a literal `*`
4. Since the result of the substitution is unquoted, the output will undergo:

   1. Word splitting: `*` becomes `*` (since it's just one word)
   2. Pathname expansion on each of the words, so `*` becomes `bin` `Desktop` `Downloads` `Photos` `public_html` according to files in the current directory
   3. Note in particular that this was *not* the same as replacing the the backtick command with the output and rerunning the result. For example, we did not consider escapes, quotes and expansions in the output, which a simple text based macro expansion would have.
5. Pass each of these as arguments to the next command (also echo): `echo bin Desktop Downloads Photos public_html`

The result is a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: ...and this is why we like `$( )` better than backticks.

Comment: So the manual could read (to simplify)

When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, a backslash is a literal backslash unless followed by a dollar sign, a backquote or another backslash, in which case it is removed?

Is this an accurate statement?

Comment: @Vonedaddy It's accurate though not complete. For example, it doesn't explicitly say that `\\\\ ` should become `\\ ` even though 3 backslashes are followed by another backslash, and although it says that ``\` `` should become `\``, it doesn't explicitly say that it should then *not* terminate the substitution.

Comment: Understood.  But the second line from the manual would cover the backquote termination. It states **The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command substitution.**  Thank you so much for your breakdown.  It really helped me wrap my head around how it works.  You are much appreciated.